# How to use a BinaryHeap when I can't implement Ord?

Tags: rust, traits, sortedlist, binary-heap

I have a the following Rust trait:

```
trait Task {
    fn time(&self) -> std::time::Duration;
    fn run(self);
}
```

I need to keep instances of `T: Task` in some kind of sorted list where I can pop the one with the lowest value for `time()`. My plan was to use a `BinaryHeap`:

```
fn foo<T: Task>(task: T) {
    let heap = std::collections::BinaryHeap::new();
    heap.push(task);
}
```

However, I run into trouble here. To put something in a `BinaryHeap`, it has to implement `Ord`:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: std::cmp::Ord` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib.rs:7:16
  |
7 |     let heap = std::collections::BinaryHeap::new();
  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::cmp::Ord` is not implemented for `T`
  |
  = help: consider adding a `where T: std::cmp::Ord` bound
  = note: required by `std::collections::BinaryHeap::<T>::new`
```

I can't implement `Ord` for `Task` since `Ord` is not from my crate. And I wouldn't want to either, since implementors of `Task` might want to have some other implementation for `Ord`.

So waht do I do? Is there some other kind of sorted list I can use? Or can I trick `BinaryHeap` into using other sorting rules?

Comment: just bound `Ord` https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fd3ea88465fc955301e4579ecfa48902 I really doubt you are asking the good question here. Your question is unclear for me

Comment: @Stargateur If I leave it up to whoever writes `T` to implement `Ord` then (a) they have to write a lot of boiler plate code, and (b) I have no idea if they are actually going to implement it the way I need it to be implemented.

Comment: I didn't understand a thing

Comment: This may be far too late to be of any use to you @Anders, but for future readers of this question it may be helpful to know that my (recently published) [copse](https://crates.io/crates/copse) crate provides an alternative `BinaryHeap` that can be instantiated with a custom/runtime-defined comparator (or at least it will, once v0.3.0 is released: the currently published versions only provide a `BTreeMap` and `BTreeSet`, but you can use the master branch from the [github repo](https://github.com/eggyal/copse) in the interim).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have multiple types of `Task`s in the same `BinaryHeap` (at the same time), you're going to need to use a boxed trait object, or some other kind of (smart) pointer. So you should implement `Ord` on the type `Box<dyn Task>`. See below if you really are just using one type of task at a time.

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;

trait Task {
    fn time(&self) -> std::time::Duration;
    fn run(self);
}


impl PartialEq for Box<dyn Task> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.time() == other.time()
    }
}

impl Eq for Box<dyn Task> {}

impl PartialOrd for Box<dyn Task> {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(&other)) // Delegate to the implementation in `Ord`.
    }
}

impl Ord for Box<dyn Task> {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.time().cmp(&other.time())
    }
}
```

Then when you insert a `Task` into the `BinaryHeap`, you'll need to box it with `Box::new` or something equivalent. Since this `Box<dyn Task>` may outlive any references in `T`, you'll have to ensure that `T` contains at most `'static` references by adding `'static` to the bounds on `T`.

```
fn foo<T: Task + 'static>(task: T) {
    let mut heap = BinaryHeap::new();

    let boxed_task: Box<dyn Task> = Box::new(task);
    heap.push(boxed_task);
}
```

Just a side note: you could also implement `Ord` (and the rest) on `dyn Task`. Then  you would get an implementation of `Ord` for `Box<dyn Task>` for free since `Box<T>` implements `Ord` if `T` does. This could be useful if you're using multiple pointer types other than `Box<T>` with `Task`s, like `Rc<dyn Task>` or `&dyn Task`.

---

If you really are just using one type at a time, then you could use a wrapper type that implements `Ord`. This looks like what you're doing right now since you only create the `BinaryHeap` once you have a specific task in hand. I don't think this is what you want, but here it is anyway.

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;

trait Task {
    fn time(&self) -> std::time::Duration;
    fn run(self);
}

struct TaskWrapper<T: Task>(T);

impl<T: Task> PartialEq for TaskWrapper<T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.0.time() == other.0.time()
    }
}

impl<T: Task> Eq for TaskWrapper<T> {}

impl<T: Task> Ord for TaskWrapper<T> {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.0.time().cmp(&other.0.time())
    }
}

impl<T: Task> PartialOrd for TaskWrapper<T> {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(&other))
    }
}
```

With this approach, if `task: T` and `T` implements `Task`, you can insert `task` into the `BinaryHeap` by wrapping it like `TaskWrapper(task)`.

```
fn foo<T: Task>(task: T) {
    let mut heap = BinaryHeap::new();
    heap.push(TaskWrapper(task));
}
```

---

Just one more thing. It's a logic error for the relative ordering of members of a `BinaryHeap` to change. Since our ordering here is based entirely off of the method `time`, the ordering might change every time `time` is called. So even in this situation, we have to depend on the correctness external implementation of `time`. You wanted to avoid using the trait bound `T: Ord` for exactly this reason, so bear this in mind.

Comment: Given the example code in the question, I believe the implementation using the `TaskWrapper` newtype is what the OP wants, and it also demonstrates the general pattern how to pass a custom order to `BinaryHeap`.

Comment: The issue about `time()` changing can be solved by snapshotting it at `TaskWrapper` creation time.